# Bash check whether my asterisk expansion has any matches

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I use the following code to search for matching files in the current directory:

```
# Check for existing backups
EXISTINGFILES="./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz"

if [[ ! -z "$EXISTINGFILES" ]]
then
    echo "Found existing backups!"
    # do stuff here...
else
    echo "Did not find any existing backups."
fi
```

This method for finding matching files allows me to iterate over matches with a loop such as `for f in $EXISTINGFILES`, but it never detects when no matching files were found.

How can I modify my code above to detect when no matching files were found??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
EXISTINGFILES=`find . -type f -name 'dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz'`
```

---

**Explanation:**

The problem with `EXISTINGFILES=./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz`, in the context of your script, is that `$EXISTINGFILES` will *always* be non-zero since you are assigning it a value ("./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz").

In the above solution, we are first *finding* the file(s) and assigning it to the variable. If the file is not found, then the variable will be zero and your script will go to the `else` block (i.e. will indicate "no matching files were found").

Comment: Perfect -- only required 1 small change to my code :) Thanks for the explanation also.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for `nullglob`.  Say:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

at the top of your script.

```
$ ls foobar*
ls: foobar*: No such file or directory
$ for i in foobar*; do echo $i; done   # Print foobar* if doesn't find match
foobar*
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for i in foobar*; do echo $i; done   # Doesn't print anything if no match found
$
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know about `shopt`s.

Answer (score 1):

Turn `existing_files` into bash array and also use `nullglob`

```
shopt -s nullglob
existing_files=(./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz)
if ((${#existing_files[@]})); then echo 'files exist'; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are quoting the asterisk both when you set the value of `EXISTINGFILES` and when you expand it, so that it is never treated as a wild-card pattern. I would skip the use of variable and use the pattern by itself like this:

```
for f in ./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz; do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
        echo "Found existing backups!"
        # do stuff here...
    else
        echo "Did not find any existing backups."
    fi
    break
done
```

If you want to store the full list of matching names, use an array:

```
EXISTINGFILES=( ./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz )
if [[ -f "${EXISTINGFILES[0]}" ]]; then
```

By default, a pattern that matches 0 files is treated literally, which is why I use `-f` in the above examples: to test if the "file" (which might be the literal pattern instead) actually exists. You can modify the default behavior so that a non-matching pattern simply vanishes instead:

```
shopt -s nullglob
EXISTINGFILES=( ./dropbox-backup-*.tar.gz )
for f in "${EXISTINGFILES[@]}"; do
    # Do stuff; there is at least one matching file if we are in
    # the body of the loop
done
```